# Can't exit an infinite loop

Tags: c++, text, colors, infinite-loop

My program starts by entering any key,then  the user sees a  color changing text "Welcome to my 
 program". Now, the user should hit any key to continue, but he can't  quit the infinite loop that is changing the color of text. Let me show you the code for a better understanding.

```c
HANDLE color=GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
cout<<"Press any key to start...";
int stop=getchar();
while(stop){
    for(i=10;i<=15;i++){
        cout <<("\n\t\t\t\t\t Welcome to my program\n");
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(color,i);
        Sleep(100);
        system("cls");
    }
}
```

Comment: The title is kind of a tautology. If you could exit, it wouldn't be infinite.

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to do. The colour should keep changing until the user presses any key?

Comment: What is the trigger you want to break out of the infinite loop?  If you add that code, does it then break out of the infinite loop?

Comment: Go through the code with your [Your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Focus the conversation on how many times `stop` is modified inside `while(stop)`'s body.

Comment: The value of `stop` is set before the loop (by calling `getchar()`.   It is never modified in the loop.   The loop itself never reads data from the user.

Comment: @ChrisMM, yes the color  keeps changing , and when the user presses any key , the loop breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a solution for you (comments included)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    HANDLE color = GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );
    std::cout << "Press any key to start...";
    bool stop = false; // use a Boolean instead of int 
    // doesn't really matter what the input is, so use getchar().
    // Note, this is really just "enter". You can modify if you expect user to 
    //   hit multiple keys before hitting enter
    getchar(); 

    // This line here will start a new thread which will wait for the user to hit enter
    std::thread getInput = std::thread( [&stop] { getchar(); stop = true; } );
    // Loop stays the same (except I inverse the "stop" variable to make more sense)
    while ( !stop ) {
        for ( int i = 10; i <= 15; i++ ) {
            std::cout << ( "\n\t\t\t\t\t Welcome to my program\n" );
            SetConsoleTextAttribute( color, i );
            Sleep( 100 );
            system( "cls" );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , it worked perfectly., 1 question I have. The code must be in the main function?I tried using a separate function and called it in main, and it printed "terminate called without an active exception".

Comment: @lucacel I'd suggest asking a new question with the code you tried which showed that error. There shouldn't be any issue moving it outside of main.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `getchar()` to get input from the user, it will store inside the integer `stop` the decimal value of the buffer the user entered.

For example: if the user entered `'0'`, the `stop` variable will store the value 48 (the decimal value of the char `'0'`).

And you while loop will keep running while `stop` is not equal to 0, which is never because the decimal value of all of the characters is not 0, the only character that its decimal value is 0 is `NULL`.

To fix your problem you will need to add an exit option according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a loop as follows:

```
int myInt = 1;

while (myInt)
{
    std::cin >> myInt;
}
```

The loop will continue until the user enters 0. This is because conditional statements use 0 as "false" and in this case, any other value as "true".

The problem with your implementation is you only get the users input once, and even if the user enters "0" (in char format) the integer value associated is 48.
You could add this:

```
    HANDLE color=GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    cout<<"Press any key to start...";
    int stop=getchar();
while(stop){
        for(i=10;i<=15;i++){
        cout <<("\n\t\t\t\t\t Welcome to my program\n");
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(color,i);
        Sleep(100);
        system("cls");
        }
    std::cin >> stop;
}
```

Now the loop will start when the user presses any key, then the the inner loop will run, then the user will need to enter a key again. If the user enters "0" this time the while() loop will break and the program will proceed.

If you are trying to keep a loop running *while* searching for user input to break the loop, then you are attempting a much more complex task. Look into the std::thread library if you are interested in this.

Comment: Yes, I would like  the infinite loop to run while searching for user input. I would definetely look into library you mentioned.

Comment: I  tried adding `std::cin>>stop` , the color keeps changing until some point where it just stops. I  would like to keep the loop running( the color is changing) and if the user presees any key, breaks it .

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code from what I could tell is that you're only initializing the variable "stop" once in your code and never inside your loop. So, the program will only ask the user for input once. A simple fix would be to continuously ask the user for input at the end of your for loop:`std::cin>>stop;`. In addition, like what others have already said, if the user inputs '0', it would implicitly typecast the char variable into an integer variable using ASCII. Since '0' corresponds to the integer value of 48, it would save 48 into the variable instead of 0. You can fix this by using this code:

```
HANDLE color=GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
cout<<"Press any key to start...";
int stop=getchar()-'0';
while(stop){
    for(i=10;i<=15;i++){
        cout <<("\n\t\t\t\t\t Welcome to my program\n");
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(color,i);
        Sleep(100);
        system("cls");
    }
std::cin>>stop;
}
```